# Hide Div when YouTube Video Ends

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

I have an absolutely placed div with an embedded YouTube video inside of it. I am placing it over another image on my website with the intention of showing first-time visitors a short video, then hiding the div with the video to reveal the original content of the page.

I know how to hide and show my div with click events, but I am very new to Javascript. I need help writing the function that would determine the YouTube video has ended and apply visibility:hidden to my div. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your going to want to take a careful look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events), paying special attention to the Events section.

you will be using

> onStateChange:
>       This event is fired whenever the player's state changes. Possible values are unstarted (-1), ended (0), playing (1), paused (2),
>   buffering (3), video cued (5). When the SWF is first loaded it will
>   broadcast an unstarted (-1) event. When the video is cued and ready to
>   play it will broadcast a video cued event (5).

and you will want to do something when the state equals 0, which means ended, something similar to the below:

```
// attach your listener
    function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
      var ytplayer = getElementById("myytplayer");
      ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
    }
// your callback function   
    function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
       if (newState === 0){
            $('yourContainingDiv').hide();
            // or if you want to just remove it...
            $('yourContainingDiv').remove();
       }
    }
```

if you are having trouble with addEventListener, check out [YouTube player api - addEventListener() does not work for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660914/youtube-player-api-addeventlistener-does-not-work-for-me)

addEventListener looks like it isn't supported by early versions of IE and might be slightly buggy

Comment: Thank you!  I am having an issue, though, that the addEventListener isn't firing. I tried adding an alert right afterwards within the same {} but it never got there. Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?  

I've tried removing all of the other JS files I'm using and moving elements of this and the swfobject.js around but nothing seems to help.

Comment: check out my edit and change your ytplayer = $('#myytplaer') to  ytplayer = getElementById("myytplayer");